# ElasticSearch synonym and word delimiter analyzer are not compatible

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I have a below mapping document, which to be precise does apply word delimiter analyzer at index and search time specifically only to model field and synonym analyzer which does a search time analysis on  search string.

**Mapping**

```
POST /stackoverflow
{
"settings":{
    "analysis":{
        "analyzer":{
            "keyword_analyzer":{
                "tokenizer":"keyword",
                "filter":[
                    "lowercase",
                    "asciifolding"
                ]
            },
            "synonym_analyzer":{
                "tokenizer":"standard",
                "filter":[
                    "lowercase",
                    "synonym"
                ],
                "expand":false,
                "ignore_case":true
            },
            "word_delimiter_analyzer":{
                "tokenizer":"whitespace",
                "filter":[
                    "lowercase",
                    "word_delimiter"

                ],
                "ignore_case":true
            }
        },
        "filter":{
            "synonym":{
                "type":"synonym",
                "synonyms_path":"synonyms.txt"
            },
            "word_delimiter":{
              "type":"word_delimiter",
              "generate_word_parts":true,
              "preserve_original": true
            }
        }
    }
},
"mappings":{
    "vehicles":{
        "dynamic":"false",
        "dynamic_templates":[
            {
                "no_index_template":{
                    "match":"*",
                    "mapping":{
                        "index":"no",
                        "include_in_all":false
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "_all":{
            "enabled":false
        },
        "properties":{
            "id":{
                "type":"long",
                "ignore_malformed":true
            },
            "model":{
                "type":"nested",
                "include_in_root":true,
                "properties":{
                    "label":{
                        "type":"string",
                        "analyzer": "word_delimiter_analyzer"
                    }
                }
            },
            "make":{
                "type":"String",
                "analyzer":"keyword_analyzer"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

and some sample data is

```
POST /stackoverflow/vehicles/6
{

    "make" : "chevrolet",
    "model" : {
       "label" : "Silverado 2500HD"
    }
}
```

The below is the search query

```
GET /stackoverflow/_search?explain
{  
   "from":0,
   "size":10,
   "query":{  
       "filtered":{  
         "query":{ 
         "multi_match":{  
            "query":"HD2500",
             "fields":[  
                "make","model.label"
              ],
            "type":"cross_fields","operator" : "OR",
            "analyzer" : "synonym_analyzer"
          }
       }
    }
   }
 }
```

THe above search query does not work, rather if i remove the synonym_analzer from the search query it works perfectly fine. I really dont understand the logic behind how synonym analyzer is tampering the result.

In my synonym.txt file i dont have any reference to HD2500, and all the synonym analyzer does is split the token via whitespace and converts it to lowercase and then try to match a synonym string and then passes it to field level analyzers, i am confused where it is getting broken.

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: well you are querying "*HD2500*" and the document has "*2500HD*" , i do not see any reason for them to match.

Comment: I am using a word delimiter, it actually index the data as "2500HD","HD","2500". It works if i remove synonym_analyzer from the query

Comment: if you remove synonym analyzer then the default search analyzer   for model.label  is word_delimiter_analyzer as a result query term HD2500 breaks into HD and 2500 and you get a match.

Comment: @keety are you saying that, only one of the analyzer will be applied at querytime? either query level or field level, am i understanding it correct?

Comment: analyzer  specified in the query level (example: multi-match) would analyze the search query (HD2500)  and the ensuing tokens would be used to match across all the fields. If no analyzer is specified the default analyzer for the field is used  which in case of label field is word_delimiter_analyzer  and the keyword analyzer for make field.